# Algolia REST Api's to apply category, Price and Brand filters using PHP curl process on Algolia?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, curl, algolia

I Have sample curl code, It is working perfectly but I don't know, how to apply filters on category, price, and brands to get all products list. we are using algolia REST API's.

```
$APPI_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$APPI_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$url ="https://xxxxxxxx-dsn.algolia.net";
$headers =  array(
'X-Algolia-Application-Id: '.$APPI_ID,
'X-Algolia-API-Key: '.$APPI_KEY
 );
//GET /1/indexes/{indexName}
$ch = curl_init($url."/1/indexes/staging_default_products?query=Avalon");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $result = json_decode($result, 1);
 //var_dump($result);
 print_r($result);
```

Comment: are you using Magento rest API endpoint?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.

I am using Algolia REST API's, to get the indexes data. my index is "staging_default_products".

First, you need algolia credentials then we can test the algolia REST Api's.

Comment: I don't get what this has to do with magento

Comment: In the mobile application, There have to fetch all products from algolia and there have to apply the filter on products. we are using algolia search. so I have to provide Algolia REST Api. In Magento 2 we are using Algolia search.

Comment: Can someone please respond.

Comment: Sir Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I look for Algolia solution, how much cost in a production server by a thousand of visitors? I would be interesting to calculate it before a try.